# UPDATE - CASE Statement - Way too many results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do a very simple data insert on a table using a case statement, see below:

```
begin tran
  update tblworkitems
  set fkidsupplier = (
    case
    when idworkitem = 214159 then 50290
    when idworkitem = 270370 then 50367
    when idworkitem = 225533 then 50453
    ...
    end )
where 
fkidtemplateitem = 654 and
fkidsupplier is null
```

I have ~85 of these explicit values.  idWorkItem is a primary key, fkidSupplier is a foreign key (Hungarian notation much?).  Problem is ~350 row are being returned.  I've done this with similar things a million times before and have never had this.

A quick check confirms no duplicates (schema should enforce this anyway):

```
select idworkitem 
from tblworkitems 
where fkidtemplateitem = 654
group by idworkitem having count(*) > 1
```

Yes, I understand the WHERE clause is invalid with these primary keys.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear, if you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblworkitems WHERE fkidtemplateitem = 654 AND fkidsupplier IS NULL`, the result is ~85?

Comment: The result is 357, but these are non-relevant results, hence the primary key reference approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the structure you have, you still update all the records that meet the criteria in `WHERE` clause. For those that are not specified in `CASE`, it will simply set `NULL`.

What you should do is to specify all records with `idworkitem` that you want to update in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Boom cheers dude, I didn't realise that CASE WHEN behaved that way.

Comment: As an experiment if I remove the where clause all ~3.2 million records are updated.  This seems counter intuitive to me (that FALSE returns across all records).  (using in (x,y,z) worked like a charm)

Comment: `CASE` always has to return something, that's why it behaves like that.